# ASUS VX24AH monitor shows wrong hue on dark colors

Tags: windows, display, colors, color-profiles

I recently bought an [ASUS VX24AH monitor](https://www.asus.com/Monitors/VX24AH/) and it shows dark colors with slightly wrong hue. Look at the sample image: (You might see it without any problem but I see how I described in the image itself.)

[image: Wrong hue on dark colors.]

I played with all monitor settings, NVIDIA control panel, color profiles and I can’t figure out what’s happening. I’m using the newest Windows 10 Enterprise but I also have this same problem in Windows 7! Is there any trick to fix this?

Comment: I would try reinstalling the graphics card drivers. BTW, does this only happen with this monitor? Did you try booting in safe mode to see if that helps?

Comment: Yes it does happen only with this monitor. I don't have seen this kind of problem in my laptop or previous monitor. and it's not from graphics driver.

Comment: I would contact support since you just bought this monitor. Hopefully they can give you a new one.

Comment: Thank you for your help but unfortunately there is no official support center for asus products here in Iran.